# Moving the cursor once max length is reached

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield

I've crudely put together this code based on some other answers on SO but I still can't get it to work. I want my cursor to move to the next `textField` once a certain length has been reached, and it does that...to an extent.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range     replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (textField.tag == 0 && range.location >= 1) {
        [_secondTextField becomeFirstResponder];
        return YES;
    } else if (textField.tag == 1 && range.location >= 2) {
        [_thirdTextField becomeFirstResponder];
        return YES;
    } else if (textField.tag == 2 && range.location >= 1) {
        [_fourthTextField becomeFirstResponder];
        return YES;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}

...

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    // catched the delegates for the input textfields
    _firstTextField.delegate = self;
    _secondTextField.delegate = self;
    _thirdTextField.delegate = self;

    [_firstTextField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

So I have 4 textfields, and I have character limits of 1, 2, and 1 for the first 3 text fields. The problem right now is the cursor will not move to the next textfield until *after* I type more text. This next text is in the new textfield, so the overall effect is achieved, but the cursor just isn't moving at the right time.

What can I do so that the cursor will move as soon as I reach the character limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way would be to use the `didChange` method like the `UITextViewDelegate` method, but as we know the `UITextFieldDelegate` does not have a `didChange` method. You can manually add behaviour. You can use the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange:` method, but personally I would advise not to override methods unless you absolutely have to.

You can add behaviour using:

```
[yourTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

And in the target method:

```
- (void)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField*)textField{

    if (textField.tag == 0 && textField.text.length == 1){

        [_secondTextField becomeFirstResponder];

    }else if (textField.tag == 1 && textField.text.length == 2){

        [_thirdTextField becomeFirstResponder];

    }else if (textField.tag == 2 && textField.text.length == 1){

        [_fourthTextField becomeFirstResponder];        
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, that worked! Thanks a lot. And it even allows me to go back and edit some of the fields too! My code wouldn't let me do that.